# Track renko close time

Tags: pine-script

Im trying to work on a simple script that will show if the renko boxes closed together at the same time. So for example: if 3 boxes close together at 0845 then the plot would go up. Can someone tell me how I could write that and get the close time?

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=4
study("Renko Plot", overlay=true)
size=input(1)
renko_tickerid = renko(syminfo.tickerid, "Traditional", size)
renko_close = security(renko_tickerid, "1", close, barmerge.gaps_off)
plot(renko_close, color=color.red, title="Renko Bar Close")
```